# MySQL: determine the fiscal quarter from a given start date and current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am given a fiscal year start date, which can change. Also given today's date: I need to get the current fiscal quarter (3 month period) based on this fiscal year start date.

I will then need to do a Select from a table of dates only within this 3 month fiscal quarter period.

For example:

- Fiscal Year Start Date: **May 2017**, Current Date: **9/14/2017**

  Based on this, we should be in the second quarter, the *current
  fiscal quarter period* is **August through October**.

  From a table of dates, select all from August through October.

Again, the Fiscal Year Start Date will change in different cases.

How to solve this in MySQL?

Comment: What is the definition of fiscal quarter? How it is defined? And how does Current Date affects Fiscal Year Start Date? Question isn't clear enough. Can you be more specific in terms of actual input & output required.

Comment: Fiscal quarter in this case, is a 3 month period, starting from the Fiscal Year start date. In the example of May 2017 as the start date, the first quarter is May-July, second quarter is Aug-Oct. We are currently in the second fiscal quarter period of Aug-Oct.

Comment: Does the fiscal year always start on 1st of a month or do you also have to consider the day?

Comment: For simplicity, let's assume we will always use the first of the month as the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of TIMESTAMPDIFF and integer division:

```
set @FiscalYearStartDate = '2017-05-01';
set @today = '2017-09-14';

select timestampdiff(month, @FiscalYearStartDate, @today) div 3 + 1;
```

http://rextester.com/HVBIE10213

To get all rows from a table with dates that are in the same quarter as today:

```
select *
from myTable t
where timestampdiff(month, '2017-05-01', curdate()) div 3
    = timestampdiff(month, '2017-05-01', t.date) div 3
```

http://rextester.com/TLHD65717

If you want to use an index you will need a more complex solution:

```
select *
from myTable t
where t.date >= '2017-05-01' + interval timestampdiff(month, '2017-05-01', curdate()) div 3 * 3 month
  and t.date <  '2017-05-01' + interval timestampdiff(month, '2017-05-01', curdate()) div 3 * 3 + 3 month
```

http://rextester.com/ZFW6858

Comment: Using this, how can I select from a table of dates, just the records that are in the Aug-Oct interval?

Comment: @FinDev its a type :P corrected!

Comment: @FinDev Do you mean you want to select rows where the date is in the 2nd quarter?

Comment: Yes exactly, in this case it is the second quarter since today's date 9/14/17 would put us in the second quarter, but if the current date changes it could put us in a different quarter as well

Comment: yes this works! thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would use the below functions:

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT('2017-05-12', '%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

Let me know if I can be of any further assistance.

Ted.

Comment: I think using date_add and interval is the right direction. I am not sure what is happening in the Date_Format function, for instance what is the 0t?